# How far am I from the top of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript/jQuery, how do I determine how far the top of my current screen is from the very top of the document?  I don't want to measure from a specific element.  I'm working on an infinite scroll page.

Comment: Store a variable named `scroll` and on every scroll event change this variable ? Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it differs between most browsers and IE. This should work for all browsers:

```
var scrollPos = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
```